# Algorithm for matching people together based on likes and dislikes

Tags: algorithm

I have a group of about 75 people. Each user has liked or disliked the other 74 users. These people need to be divided in about 15 groups of various sizes (4 tot 8 people). They need to be grouped together so that the groups consist only of people who all liked eachother, or at least as much as possible.

I'm not sure what the best algorithm is to tackle this problem. Any pointers or pseudo code much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

This isn't formed quite well enough to suggest a particular algorithm.  I suggest clustering and "clique" algorithms, but you'll still need to define your "best grouping" metric.  "as much as possible", in the face of trade-offs and undefined desires, is meaningless.  Your clustering algorithm will need this metric to form your groups.

Data representation is simple: you need a directed graph.  An edge from A to B means that A likes B; lack of an edge means A doesn't like B.  That will encode the "likes" information in a form tractable to your algorithm.  You have 75 nodes and one edge for every "like".

Start by researching clique algorithms; a "clique" is a set in which every member likes every other member.  These will likely form the basis of your clustering.

Note, however, that you have to define your trade-offs.  For instance, consider the case of 13 nodes consisting of two distinct cliques of 4 and 8 people, plus one person who likes one member of the 8-clique.  There are no other "likes" in the graph.

How do you place that 13th person?  Do you split the 8-clique and add them to the group with the person they like?  If so, you do split off 3 or 4 people form the 8?  Is it fair to break 15 or 16 "likes" to put that person with the one person they like -- who doesn't like them?  Is it better to add the 13th person to the mutually antagonistic clique of 4?

Your eval function must return a well-ordered metric for all of these situations.  It will need to support adding to a group, splitting a large group, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a clustering problem.
Each user is a node. If two users liked each other, there is a path between the nodes.
If users disliked each other, or one like another but not the other way around, then there is no path between those nodes.

Once you process the like information into a graph, you will get a connected graph (maybe some nodes will be isolated if no one likes that user). Now the question becomes how to cut that graph into clusters of 4-8 connected nodes, which is a well studied problem with a lot of possible algorithms:

https://www.google.com/search?q=divide+connected+graph+into+clusters

If you want to differentiate between the cases when two people dislike each other vs one person likes another and that person dislikes the first one, than you can also introduce weight on the path - each like is +1, and dislike is -1. Then the question becomes that of partitioning a weighted graph.

Comment: I think the problem is a lot more complicated than just that. A group doen't only contain a pair of people who like each other but ideally all of them like each other if possible. So if you put `(1,2,3,4,5)` in a group and they all like each other then that's the best match than say `(1,2,3,4,5)` where `(1,2)` liked each other but `3`  didn't like `2` etc. I don't know if your explanation is taking that into account. If it is then I misunderstood.

Comment: @ustulation My idea is simply to convert a problem to well known problem of clustering a graph by converting likes and users to a nodes in connected graph, where a connection between nodes represents mutual like. I haven't proposed any concrete algorithm on how to partition the graph because there are many ways to do it, each having some advantages and disadvantages.